Batch file with disk part
I've been trying to create a batch file that calls out diskpart commands and then exits back to the batch file. The diskpart commands increase the size of the recovery partition.
Here is the current batch file I have:
@echo off
reagentc /disable
diskpart /s diskpartincreasepartition.txt
reagentc /enable
exit /b

And here's what I have in the diskpartincreasepartition.txt file:
diskpart
list disk
sel disk 0
list part
sel part 5
shrink desired=1000 minimum=1000
sel part 4
delete partition override
create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
gpt attributes =0x8000000000000001
format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows RE tools"
exit

Right now, it just calls diskpart and doesn't do anything else. I have both the .bat and .txt files saved to my USB drive with nothing else on it. I am running the .bat file that calls out the .txt file. What am I doing wrong here?

I see no reason to have diskpart as the first line of your text file. Have you tried removing that?

I also see no obvious reason to use list disk before sel disk 0 or to use list part before sel part 5 either, so you can remove those two lines too.

Your script looks for the diskpartincreasepartition.txt in the current working folder - which may be the same folder where the batch script is located, or a completely different one (usually). It doesn't find the file there, so diskpart has nothing to do. Give it the full path:
diskpart /s "%~dp0diskpartincreasepartition.txt"


This worked flawlessly. Thank you, Stephan!! Much appreciated.

If you want to include diskpart commands directly into the batch:
@echo off
reagentc /disable
(
echo list disk
echo sel disk 0
echo list part
echo sel part 5
echo shrink desired=1000 minimum=1000
echo sel part 4
echo delete partition override
echo create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
echo gpt attributes =0x8000000000000001
echo format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows RE tools"
echo exit
) | diskpart.exe
reagentc /enable
exit /b

